# How to apply Bubble Sort to the data stored in different Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Can I sort this code below based on the number ?

Like if the data is sorted, let's say ascending it should look like:

```
001  Graciella
012  Steven
094  Marcellin

... and so on
```

*My code:*

```
String [][] sis = new String [][] {
    {"001",  "980", "777", "169","094","233", "012"},
    {"Graciella","Martinus","Renata","Vianney","Marcellin", "Joakim", "Steven"}
};      

System.out.println(sis[0][0]+" "+ sis[1][0]);
System.out.println(sis[0][1]+" "+ sis[1][1]);
System.out.println(sis[0][2]+" "+ sis[1][2]);
System.out.println(sis[0][3]+" "+ sis[1][3]);
System.out.println(sis[0][4]+" "+ sis[1][4]);
System.out.println(sis[0][5]+" "+ sis[1][5]);
System.out.println(sis[0][6]+" "+ sis[1][6]);
```

I have tried the following, but I feel like I did something wrong. But I don't know what.

```
String num [] = {"001", "980", "777", "169", "094", "233", "012"};
int NUM [] = new int[num.length];
        
for (int i = 0; i < NUM.length;i++) {
    NUM[i] = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
}
        
String nem [] = {"Graciella","Martinus","Renata","Vianney","Marcellin", "Joakim", "Steven"};
        
        
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (num[j].compareTo(num[j+1]) > 0) {
            String temp = num[j];
            num[j] = num[j+1];
            num[j+1]= temp;
        }
    }
}
        
System.out.println();
        
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (nem[j].compareTo(nem[j+1]) > 0) {
            String temp = nem[j];
            nem[j] = nem[j+1];
            nem[j+1]= temp;
        }
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    System.out.println(num[j] + " " + nem[j]);
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? And can I sort this data based on the name?

Comment: You are using parallel arrays instead of a proper type. Don't do that.

Comment: It's never too early to learn about the debugger within an IDE (if you're using one), which would make your life a lot easier to see where issues are cropping up.

Comment: Try the Intellij IDE and its debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html. It will help you understand what is happening under the shell.

Answer (score 1):

As *@Elliott Frisch* has pointed out in the comments, it would be way easier and cleaner if you treated these data as **objects** instead of keeping *persons* properties scattered among two different arrays, which make your solution brittle and unflexible.

That's how the `Person` class might look like:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%03d %s", id, name);
    }
}
```

And that how we can implement bubble sort.

*Note:* there's no need to iterate through the hole array in the nested loop (condition `j < 6`) each time because `i` elements at the very end of the array are already sorted. The highest element from the unsorted part "bubbles up" at each iteration step and takes its place before the start of the sorted part.

Also, hard-coding values like in the condition `j < 6` is a bad practice. Use method parameters, their attributes, static constants, etc., and not hard-coded values. Even if your logic would be flawless, it would already cause you troubles because you have `7` elements in each array, not `6`.

```
public static void sortPeopleWithBubbleSort(Person[] people) {
    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < people.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (people[j].getId() > people[j + 1].getId()) {
                Person temp = people[j + 1];
                people[j + 1] = people[j];
                people[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person[] people = new Person[]{
        new Person(1, "Graciella"),
        new Person(980, "Martinus"),
        new Person(777, "Renata"),
        new Person(169, "Vianney"),
        new Person(94, "Marcellin"),
        new Person(233, "Joakim"),
        new Person(12, "Steven")
    };
    // sorting
    sortPeopleWithBubbleSort(people);
    // printing
    for (Person person: people) {
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
001 Graciella
012 Steven
094 Marcellin
169 Vianney
233 Joakim
777 Renata
980 Martinus
```

As *@hfontanez* suggested in the comments, we can make `sortPeopleWithBubbleSort()` method more flexible by providing and additional argument - [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) (a special object which is used to compare objects that have no *natural order*).

It might look like that:

```
// sorting by id
Comparator<Person> byId = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getId);

sortPeopleWithBubbleSort(people, byId);
```

```
// sorting by name
Comparator<Person> byName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName);

sortPeopleWithBubbleSort(people, byName);
```

```
public static void sortPeopleWithBubbleSort(Person[] people,
                                            Comparator<Person> comparator) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < people.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (comparator.compare(people[j], people[j + 1]) > 0) {
                Person temp = people[j + 1];
                people[j + 1] = people[j];
                people[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To learn how to build *comparators* using Java-8 methods, have a look at this [*post*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing). And if you are not comfortable with Java 8 functional programming features, it would be better to start with this [*tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: This is the best solution (so far). You could even use a `Comparator` to compare two `Person` objects by name and/or by ID AND you could compare in any other (by name then by ID or vice versa). Encapsulating meaningful data (like this) in a class is one of the reasons why classes exist. And you can easily change the sort criteria (sort by ID only or by name only) and never have to worry that names and IDs will ever get out of sync.

Comment: @hfontanez Agree it makes the method more flexible, updated the answer. I was doubting about adding the code with comparator, because it requires a knowledge of generic types and at least vague familiarity with lambdas/method references because since Java 8 implementing compactor using anonymous class is not an encouraged practice.

Comment: Your answer was pretty much perfect the way it was originally written. That said, this was the enhancement I was thinking of. Nice work! I agree with your original thinking, especially for this OP.

Answer (score 0):

I added comments to the code for explaining. I did not include some best-code practices (i.e. do not duplicate code) I just focused on alghorithm.

Also easiest would be to first create new array that connects the two strings (number and name) together and then sort just this extra array. However I do not know if you need the original arrays sorted for other reasons, therefore I kept it as it is.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (num[j].compareTo(num[j+1]) > 0) {                   
                String temp = num[j];
                num[j] = num[j+1];
                num[j+1]= temp;

                // You need to switch this as well as you keep it as pair, so it has to be
                // in same position after shift

                temp = nem[j];
                nem[j] = nem[j+1];
                nem[j+1]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            // only if the number is the same, then check which string has priority
            if (nim[j] == nim[j+1] && nem[j].compareTo(nem[j+1]) > 0) {
                String temp = nem[j];
                nem[j] = nem[j+1];
                nem[j+1]= temp;

                // You need to keep the other array in sync
                temp = num[j];
                num[j] = num[j+1];
                num[j+1]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
```